# Do gyroscopes purposefully show erroneous data?

Tags: gyroscope, accelerometer, mpu6050

I tested an [MPU-6050 (GY-521)](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050#.Uzl8TvldU-0) using an Arduino Nano. I used the I2CDevLib and opened the [MPU6050_DMP6.ino](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050/Examples/MPU6050_DMP6) with the Arduino IDE. I opened the [MPUTeapot.pde](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050/Examples/MPU6050_DMP6/Processing) Processing-file with Processing. A few changes was necessary to make it work:

```
MPU6050 mpu;
```

was changed into:

```
MPU6050 mpu(0x68);
```

Additionally I commented out this line:

```
#define OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL
```

and uncommented this line:

```
#define OUTPUT_TEAPOT
```

When turning everything on, the arrow (Processing) would turn with 5 degrees/s clockwise around the z-axis (plus a very small amount around the other two axes). After about 20 seconds, it would stop, and turn around the x-axis pretty fast for 3 seconds. Then it would stop. Now, the gyroscope+accelerometer would work perfectly. This happens every time I test it.

This happens only when the gyroscope is perfectly still on the ground. It does not stabilize if I move it around. Only after it is left completely still, it'll stabilize after 23 seconds.

Is this how it should work, or is it a problem with the gyroscope? Could it even be caused by the I2CDevLib? Can anybody else confirm this?

Comment: According to the datasheet, that was conveniently linked in your question, there is a temperature sensor in the device. Does your code compensate for temperature, because it does seem to be heating up. What happens when you warm the device with your finger once it is stable?

Comment: @jippie I'll check.

Comment: @jippie It doesn't do anything even if heated up. There is a lot of code to read through for me who is new to Arduino and don't know much C++. But it claims to use some processor inside the chip to process the raw data from the gyroscope and accelerometer and temperature sensor..

Comment: @jippie: How did you see that link *before* I edited it into the question?

Answer (score 1):

MPU6050 is a chip that has an intenal (closed and unknown) algorith to calculate orientation. Because you ar reading ANGLE, that means you are using that algoritm, and that "time" may be the time needed for the calibration.

what do you have as output on the serial?

Comment: It happens every time I close and reopen the serial on the computer. So it would be strange if it is actually it heating up. What do you mean by output on the serial?

Comment: every time you open/close the serial you are resetting the arduino (see autoreset feature) so yes, it reinforce the "warm up" theory. Track on the serial the time used by every step!

Comment: Do you imply that the Arduino is trying to compensate for the heating up which does not take place because it's already turned on?

Comment: no, i think the algoritm used by the chip is doing some reading to calibrate itself. Many chip has internal activable BIAS, for example on Accelerometer activating this bias you add a -+1G, so you can calculate the real value of G, linearity of value, if it is stable, and a lot of thing used to compensate for real world "noise". Fixing "warmup" to "calibration" in the answer, so it will be clear